# Add a Bootstrap css stylesheet to Gluon scenebuilder for JavaFX

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, javafx, scenebuilder, gluon

There is a bootstrap add-on to JavaFX by Kordamp, which per the documentation can be used through programmatic access (direct modification of Java objects) (https://github.com/kordamp/bootstrapfx).

I'd like to use this bootstrap css framework, but accessed through the Gluon SceneBuilder. I see there is an "add css stylesheet" in the menu of the SceneBuilder but I am not sure how this can be combined with the add-on mentioned above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to put the `bootstrapfx-core` JAR (https://search.maven.org/search?q=org.kordamp.bootstrapfx) in the classpath where SceneBuilder can find it. I believe SB has a menu option for adding JARs to the classpath.

Next you have to apply the bootstrapfx stylesheet, I'd suggest applying to the root of the the node hierarchy, or the container/pane where you want Bootstrap styles to be used. The stylesheet `"org/kordamp/bootstrapfx/bootstrapfx.css"` is available from the classpath.

Finally add style classes to the components you want to update. A lists of available styles can be found in the README. https://github.com/kordamp/bootstrapfx#supported-css-classes